# Drop M values from MULTIPOLYGON with PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, m-values

The title is self-explanatory. I wonder if there is a simple function like `ST_Force2D` for the M values?

Comment: by "strip out" do you mean extract M values? or drop the M dimension?

Comment: @mikeT I mean drop the M dimension.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function is `ST_Force3D` if you have XYZM geometry, if it's XYM you should use `ST_Force_2D`.

From the [manual](http://www.postgis.org/docs/reference.html):

- ST_Force_2D — Forces the geometries into a "2-dimensional mode" so that all output   representations will only have the X and Y coordinates.
- ST_Force_3D — Forces the geometries into XYZ mode. This is an alias for ST_Force_3DZ.
- ST_Force_3DZ — Forces the geometries into XYZ mode. This is a synonym for ST_Force_3D.
- ST_Force_3DM — Forces the geometries into XYM mode.
- ST_Force_4D — Forces the geometries into XYZM mode.

Answer (score 2):

From Postgis 2.1.0. [Reference](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.5/reference.html#Geometry_Editors)

- ST_Force2D — Force the geometries into a "2-dimensional mode".
- ST_Force3D — Force the geometries into XYZ mode. This is an alias for ST_Force3DZ.
- ST_Force3DZ — Force the geometries into XYZ mode.
- ST_Force3DM — Force the geometries into XYM mode.
- ST_Force4D — Force the geometries into XYZM mode.